# how to pass ASP.NET MVC view values to angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass ASP.NET MVC view (.cshtml) values to angular js controller. I am familiar with Angular js, But not on MVC. I have values in MVC cshtml. I want to pass that value to my angular controller. Please provide me some info or demo project or link which explains in detail.

i want somthing like below,

1. Get value from mvc model and pass it to cshtml.
2. from cshtml pass value to angular js controller and display in angular html page
   I do not want to use cshtml as my view. I want to get data from cshtml to angular controller and display in seperate html

Comment: Could you share with us some sample? What have you come up with so far? Stackoverflow is meant to help with a problem you come across in your code. There are plenty of examples online.

Comment: MVC uses routing as the main driver behind its framework. So you need to wire up the controller action with the view/partial view and call the action via a WebApi like call. items/1/demo. This link should get you there http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1012/angularjs-routing-aspnet-mvc-application

Comment: try going through this article on CodeProject, it might help, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Comment: i understand there are docs , but everywhere they are using webapi calls. i want to make only one call to get all the data from cshtml to angular controller. If you ahve any docs also it will help

Comment: I do not want to use cshtml as my view. I want to get data from cshtml to angular controller and display in seperate html

Comment: Well since a controller is supposed to be created for a single view this shouldn't be too difficult. This should be basic Angular.js stuff using it just as if it was regular MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Using the very first [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par) I pulled up I grabbed this snippet:

```
var AwesomeAngularMVCApp = angular.module('AwesomeAngularMVCApp', ['ngRoute']);

AwesomeAngularMVCApp.controller('HomeController', HomeController);

var configFunction = function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Listings', {
            url: 'routesDemo/one'
        })
        .when('/Listing', {
            url: 'routesDemo/two'
        })
        .when('/Listings', {
            url: 'routesDemo/three'
        });
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

AwesomeAngularMVCApp.config(configFunction);
```

Now this how you link a view to a controller action in MVC:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AwesomeAngularMVCApp.Controllers
{
    public class RoutesDemoController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult One(string title)
        {
            var listings = db.Articles.Contain(title);
            return PartialView(listings, "..\Views\Shared\WhateverPartialView.cshtml");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Two(Article article)
        {
            if(ModelState.isValid){
                  _db.Add(article)
            }
            return View(article); //This one returns entire page
        }

        public JsonResult Three(string title)
        { 
            var listing = db.Articles.Where(t => t.Title == title).SingleOrDefault();
            return Json(listing, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

These partial views would be in the Views folder in a sub folder RoutesDemo

1. one.cshtml GET
2. two.cshtml POST ie: `a href="#/Article/6" type=submit" class="btn"`

   $("form").submit( function(){
        $.ajax( function(url, data){
   });
   });
3. three.cshtml GET ie

   $.ajax({
                       url: '@Url.Action("routeDemo", "three")',
                       //url: baseUrl + url,
                       data: {
                           search: searchBlue.val()
                       },
                       success: function (data) {
                           $("#msg").html("Results for" + searchBlue.val());
                           searchBlue.searchMeme({ searchComplete: true });
                           $('#main').fadeOut(800, function () {
                               $('#main').html("" + data + "").fadeIn().delay(800);
                           });
                           searchBlue.val("");
                       },
                       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                           alert(error);
                       }
   });

If you want to pass values to the angular controller use razor syntax and bind the value to the html input. The top of the view file will make it so angular knows what type of object to expect.

IE: Top of Two.cshtml

```
 @model AwesomeAngularMVCApp.Article
```

That should be it besides route.config for angular

If you want to handle the Model object using razor syntax check out this [tutorial](http://www.dematte.org/2014/01/08/MixingAngularJSAndASPNETMVC.aspx). Pretty cut and dry.If that is not enough I will show example of binding @Model.attribute/property to an html element after work tomorrow

**EDIT**

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="PersonDetailsController" ng-init="personId=@Model.Id">
```

Angular injects it in the scope during initialization, so you can refer to it as `$scope.personId`

Comment: here we are using cs.html to display....i donot want this. i will make it very simple. Now Let us say there is some value in cshtml file eg: <td> id </td> which is coming from mvc controller. now i want to pass this id to my angular controller. I do not want to disturb mvc controller or write any code in that. I just want to pass cshtml id value to angular controller. Here mvc and angular will act seperatly . I want to pass cshtml value to angular controller. Its only between cshtml and angular controller. How can i do this?

Comment: You dont have to disturb it. They are both on the client so what you can do is var id = @Model.Id using Razor.

Comment: @yardpenalty how angular sense Razor syntax like `ng-init="personId=@Model.Id"` using  @model.id ?

Comment: I had almost same requirement where I need to pass the value to ngModule. Value is passed using ng-init but need to convert to string using ToString() function. e.g. ng-init="personId=@Model.Id.ToString()" and fetched via $scope.$parent.personId